# GET request to Android phone

Tags: android, node.js, ipv6, http-get, sms-gateway

I'm trying to use my phone as an SMS gateway using the [SMS Gateway](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.apksoft.android.smsgateway) app.

The app listens to an HTTP GET request, extracts the phone number and message out of the request, then sends and SMS.

The app gives the following target URL:
**http://fe80::57ee::c539:6741%rmnet0:9090/sendsms** (not the real IP)

My questions are:

1. Why does this look like IPv6 although my phone has an IPv4 address?
2. How to include `"%rmnet0"` in the HTTP request?
3. What is wrong with the `node.js` code below? (IP and phone numbers redacted)

   ```
   var request = require('request');

   function send(phone,message){

    // Set the headers
    var headers = {
       'User-Agent':       'Domogeek/4',
       'Content-Type':     'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    };

    // Configure the request
    var options = {
       url: "http://fe80::57ee::c539:6741%rmnet0:9090/sendsms",
       // url: "http://92.90.21.38:9090/sendsms",
       method: 'GET',
       headers: headers,
       qs: {'phone': phone, 'text': message}
    };

       console.log('GET request');

    // Start the request
    request(options, function (error, response, body) {
       if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
           console.info('SMS sended to: %s => %s', phone, message);
       } else {
           console.error('SMS error : %s => %s', error, message);
       }
    });


   }    
   send('00684060640','welcome');
   ```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The app is choosing the wrong address.  That is a link-local address, it begins with fe80, and can't be used from an external connection.  See [here about the reachability scope % sign](https://superuser.com/questions/99746/why-is-there-a-percent-sign-in-the-ipv6-address)

Take a look at your ifconfig or netcfg depending on your version of Android and see what address(s) your phone has.

Comment: Thanks, so the app is listening to a local interface. Would Android forward an incoming request to that link-local address? How would that work?

Answer (score 0):

Your phone has IPv6 because *all* modern phones have IPv6. It is a mandatory protocol for 4G LTE. IPv4 is optional, and a phone might not have IPv4 addresses configured at all (in this case, the mobile phone network uses some translation technology such as NAT64/DNS64 to present IPv4 resources to the phone via IPv6).

The proper way to format an IPv6 literal in a URL is within brackets. For instance:

```
http://[fe80::57ee::c539:6741%rmnet0]:9090/sendsms
```

But be aware that some HTTP client implementations are not capable of connecting to IPv6 link-local addresses. In this case, you will probably need to contact the app developer for advice (or more likely to report a bug).